# FPDF Cell o Multicell

Tags: php, fpdf

Buenas tardes a todos,

tengo un problema con un texto que es demasiado largo para la celda, y no sé si se peude que Cell o Multicell ajusten paraque el texto tan largo entre en una misma celda pero en dos líneas.

He probado estas dos opciones y ambas me crean una celda nueva:

```
$pdf->Cell(101,8,utf8_decode("Producto alimenticio de alto valor nutricional, excelente para deportistas"),1,1,'L','true');  
$pdf->Multicell(101,8,utf8_decode("Producto alimenticio de alto valor nutricional, excelente para deportistas"),1,1,'L','true');
```

¿Alguna idea?? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer se puede conseguir usando un [`MultiCell`](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/multicell.htm). Es importante indicar los parámetros correctamente, algo que al parecer no estas haciendo (*los parámetros para un `MultiCell` tiene distinto orden que los del `Cell`*).

Algo que debes considerar es que cuando indicas el alto (`$height`) dicho valor **es el alto de cada línea (*o renglón*)** y no el alto total de la celda.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(101, 4, utf8_decode("Producto alimenticio de alto valor nutricional, excelente para deportistas"), 1, 'L');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, entonces tengo que calcular la altura del multicell en funcion de los renglones que tenga?? Por ejemlo si tengo 2 renglones 4 y si tengo uno 8 en caso de que los cell() que tenga seean de altura 8.

Comment: Si, pero también debes definir un alto mínimo para las celdas, el cual va a depender de alto de la fuente, de lo contrario el texto se puede superponer.

Comment: Para una multicelda como bien dice Marcos:  $this->MultiCell(137,25,'',1); primero el ancho de la celda  w: 137,  el alto de la celda h: 25,(Aquí me permite colocar 5 celdas de alto de 5 equivalente a decir que son 5 renglones. ,  txt: ""  vacío en mi caso, border = 1. si quieres o no borde.